# Nullable nested mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

I have problem on nested mapping, when source member is null and destination - not.

```
public class UserModel { public string FullName { get; set; } }
public class PersonModel { public UserModel User { get; set; } }
public class StudentModel { public string UserFullName { get; set; } }

CreateMap<PersonModel, StudentModel>();

var src = new PersonModel { User = null };
var dest = new StudentModel { UserFullName = "Truman Burbank" };
var result = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(src, dest);
```

Cause of *User* is *null* in source object, destination member is *null* too (Nested Mapping).
In older versions of AutoMapper (ex. in 3.2.1), it will be "ignored" and destination member will not be mapped on *null* value.

Is there any way or AutoMapper property (in current version - v7.0.0), to ignore source member's null value and do not change destination member's value ("Truman Burbank" in this example)?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Conditional-mapping.html

Comment: I'm using Condition -s right now.. Is there any configuration property somewhere in AutoMapper..? Thanks for answer

Comment: No, there isn't.